# Flutter ScrollController maxScrollExtent equals to 0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created a design for a chat application, and tried to scroll to end automatically, I used this code

```dart
scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
 );
```

nothing happens, ofc the list has the controller applied

```dart
child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: chatMessage.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ChatBubble(
                    chatMessage: chatMessage[index],
                    isDark: widget._isDark,
                  );
                },
              )
```

I tried to print the maxScrollExtent to see if something was wrong.
Both the max and min scrollExtent are equals to 0.0.
The animateTo function is also call in a postFrameCallback.
The listview length is always 20 has, for now, it's a simple list.

Comment: didn't work, the max and min are still at 0.0, and nothing occurs

Comment: still the same, I tried one and two seconds

Comment: yeah, it's ```true```

Comment: only usable with listwheelscrollview and I dont really like the look

Comment: yeah but chat items height will probably never be the same sooo

Comment: maybe remove `shrinkWrap: true,`

Comment: I get ```Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.``` without it

Comment: so your listview is inside some other scrollable widget, right? most likely thats why your maxScrollExtent is never assignrd

Comment: oh I completely forgot I added a scrollview at first

Comment: working perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: @pskink My listview is inside Column but still I get max and min 0.0?
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that my ListView was inside a ScrollView. Removing the ScrollView fixed the issue.

Comment: Any solution for this